# Swift search value for the nearest similar value reagrdless of sequence

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Hi guys I want to ask how do you search the items for the nearest possible similar value regarding of the sequence. Example as below when I search for ["Restaurant","Bull"], it should return me str2 is the possible nearest values. Because this function only able to work for order sequence, it cannot for non-sequence. I really hope you guys can help me out....

```
 func search(`for` searchItems: Set<String>, `in` searchArea: [Set<String>]) -> Set<String>? {
            return searchArea.max(by: { (a, b) -> Bool in
                return searchItems.intersection(a).count < searchItems.intersection(b).count || searchItems.intersection(a).count > searchItems.intersection(b).count
            })
        }        


            let str2: Set<String> = ["Bull","Restaurant","Corner"]
            let str3: Set<String> = ["Corner","Restaurant","Mole"]

            let area = [str3, str2] as [Any]

            print("search result",self.search(for: ["Restaurant","Bull"], in: area as! [Set<String>]))
```

Comment: what do you meant by "cannot for non-sequence"?

Comment: It means when i search with ["restaurant","bull"] it will return true result if with ["bull","restaurant"] it wont... This is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because your `str2` and `str3` is not `Set` at all, it's array coz you are using array declaration, thus change it to this then it works if you use `["Bull", "Restaurant"]`:

```
let str2 = Set(["Bull","Restaurant","Corner"])
let str3 = Set(["Corner","Restaurant","Mole"])
```

Also, `Set` is non-ordered sequence, `Array` is ordered sequence

Answer (score 0):

Just make a set out of your query array and use its `isSubset(of:)` method to check wether it's a subset of your data.

```
let set1 = Set([1,2,3])
let set2 = Set([2,3,4])

let query = [1,2]
let querySet = Set(query)

querySet.isSubset(of: set1) // true
querySet.isSubset(of: set2) // false

let query2 = [2,1]
let querySet2 = Set(query)

querySet2.isSubset(of: set1) // true
querySet2.isSubset(of: set2) // false
```